# Writing a non-blocking stdin read function for Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm writing a program for Windows that perform server-client relations.

I'm using `select()` so as to get the client's requests, and also the user's commands(the one behind the server, physically) from the stdin.

It seems that the `select()` works for the client's requests, but not for the input from the stdin.

Also, i don't succeed to `ReadFile()` from the `stdin` because the latter is not monitored, in other words it is not `FD_SET(stdin, (fd_set)myread_fds)`. Is there a way to get an input from the stdin in a non-blocking way?

Answer (score 2):

Your plan for your server design is very challenging.  Many fine programmers have attempted it and eventually given up.  Even if you can get it work, it is not going to be scalable.

A better plan, IMHO, is to write a separate application, that looks after the 'server user' commands.  This application, call it the SUG ( server user gui ) is another client of the server.  The server looks after both requests from the SUG and the remote clients in the same way.  This makes the server design simpler, and the GUI does not interfere with the performance of the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is not select() but WaitForMultipleObjects() which can wait for both sockets and console I/O.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx